# MutableMap modified by multiple threads and map.size not equal to key count

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, hashcode, concurrenthashmap

I am using Kotlin and I have a mutableMap with Key as String, when I have 2 threads trying to access and put with same key, some weird things happen that my log shows the map size is 2 (not 1), I also log the key and value there but there is only one entry...

```
@Component
class CacheImpl {
protected val cache: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap() //same behavior with ConcurrentHashMap

fun fetchFromCache(key: String) {
   log.info("cache size: ${cache.size}")
   log.info("cache keys: ${cache.keys}")
   log.info("cache keys count: ${cache.keys.count()}")
   cache.computeIfAbsent(id) {
       key -> fetchFromClient(key)
   }
}
}

fun serviceCall() {
  // should fetch from client
  val result1 = cache.fetchFromCache("123")
  // should fetch from service
  val result2 = cache.fetchFromCache("123")
}
```

So I have 2 threads calling the serviceCall at same time, in log I found

```
[thread: 2] - cache size: 0
[thread: 4] - cache size: 0
[thread: 2] - cache keys: []
[thread: 4] - cache keys: []
[thread: 2] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 2] - cache size: 2
[thread: 2] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 2] - cache keys: [123]
[thread: 4] - cache size: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys: [123]
```

I also tried with LinkedHashMap and it's even more weird, in LinkedHashMap you can see my map contains two exact same key!

```
[thread: 2] - cache size: 0
[thread: 4] - cache size: 0
[thread: 2] - cache keys: []
[thread: 4] - cache keys: []
[thread: 2] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 2] - cache size: 2
[thread: 2] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 2] - cache keys: [123,123]
[thread: 4] - cache size: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys count: 2
[thread: 4] - cache keys: [123,123]
```

- shouldn't Map only maintain a unique key always?
- Why my map size is not matching with key count?

Answer (score 0):

The HashMap is not thread-safe, so when you put in two threads, it happened the weird scene. I suggest you use the `ConcurrentWeakMap`. as the doc says

> This is a very limited implementation, not suitable as a generic map replacement.
> // It has lock-free get and put with synchronized rehash for simplicity (and better CPU usage on contention)

But it only makes sure the map operation is thread-safe, you have to make the method thread-safe.

```
@Synchronized
fun fetchFromCache(key: String) {
   log.info("cache size: ${cache.size}")
   log.info("cache keys: ${cache.keys}")
   log.info("cache keys count: ${cache.keys.count()}")
   cache.computeIfAbsent(id) {
       key -> fetchFromClient(key)
   }
}
```

At the same time, the key you use generates from fetchFromClient, every time it returns a new object. it is also the reason. you should use the `putIfAbseent`, if you want override the value which has exits

Comment: I have tried ConcurrentHashMap already and it's same behavior, please see my comment in code

Comment: I don't think it's only race condition, as you can see even using concurrent hashmap, there are still 2 same keys inserted, refer to use with linked hashmap I was able to output all keys and they are same

Comment: @KevD. Ok, I understand, The ConcurrentHashMap only can make sure the map operation is thread-safe, but your method is in the multi-thread situation, the only wat is to make the method thread-safe use synchronized. you can try it